# Visual Studio 2013 JSLint validation?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, jslint

I would like to know if there is any build in JSLint validation tool in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate edition, or optionally a recommand extentsion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is - [jslintnet](https://jslintnet.codeplex.com/). It doesn't matter whether Visual studio is Pro, Ultimate or whatever... 
You could install it from [vs gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ede12aa8-0f80-4e6f-b15c-7a8b3499370e) or download from [codeplex](https://jslintnet.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 5):

The Web Essentials extension (MUST HAVE!) also has JSHint embedded: http://vswebessentials.com/features/javascript

Answer (score 2):

There is also a [NuGet package for JSLint.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JSLintNet.MSBuild/) that adds JavaScript validation targets to any Visual Studio project. That broadens the reach of JSLint.NET to just about any Visual Studio version, including older and Express editions.